# What is the best way to make Jhipster auto generated application have SAAS model?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jhipster, multi-tenant

Like Jhipster generated app has out of box user management, I want to create a company/organization concept in JHipster so that every data is associated with its own organization/company

What is the best approach to handle it?
Have someone done it before?

Answer (score 1):

First, for the database you should look at multitenancy in Hibernate and precisely at the discriminator column approach described in
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy and  https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy

Then, for the REST layer, you should consider implementing a Spring MVC interceptor to map authenticated user to tenant id. For debugging purpose, you should also consider setting the tenant id in logback MDC so that you can see it in logs.

Finally, you got to think at the admin part, administrators should probably be able to access all data from all tenants. If admins should not be allowed to do so, you should consider encrypting data with a key per tenant.

There's a blueprint but it's not working for current JHipster 7 and team is looking for contributors. However, there are examples generated that you could look at for inspiration, https://sonalake.com/latest/multi-tenant-applications-with-jhipster/